This image cannot be processed by the web server. Convert it to JPEG or PNG before uploading

This image cannot be processed by the web server. Convert it to JPEG
or PNG before uploading.

description: https://ibb.co/r31V1gk

Can you provide more information? A screenshot and a copy paste of a general error message isn't always enough, what was the file you were trying to upload? This is a stack for developers do you have the code or is this a user support issue? Use the edit link to update your question with more information

In my wordpress version 6.5.2, I cannot upload images in webp format, when uploading I receive an error message: This image cannot be processed by the web server. Convert it to JPEG or PNG before uploading.

From your comment I understand you are trying to upload a webp image. This format is supported since WordPress 5.8. However, for this to actually work, your server needs webp support as well. The error message says this is not the case.
More in detail: the PHP installation on the server comes with one or two image libraries that do the hard work in handling media: ImageMagick and LibGD. Both in principle support webp, but not in all installations. It looks like on your server, they do not.
Since WP uses ImageMagick by default, you could try switching to GD to see if that library has webp support on your server.
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'wpse425693_prefer_gd_over_imagick' );
function wpse425693_prefer_gd_over_imagick($array) {
    return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}

If this doesn't work you'll have to contact your hosting provider and ask them to add webp support.
UPDATE
For those who wonder why providers may be reluctant to allow webp support: there are security issues with this format. Google for "webp vulnerability" to get the latest news.

Dad ran into a similar issue recently with his website. It should be noted that his WordPress software was updated to a version which should have been able to handle .WEBP.
What we did was simply upload the .WEBP file via the FTP, copied the URL for the image, and then used "Insert from URL" when adding the image to the page in WordPress. It showed up as a broken image until we pressed "Publish" and then checked the live site. Then it appeared with no issue.

using 'insert from URL' is a bit slower, in my observation. I have done it a lot of times, images uploaded to the media library appear quickly in the web-page, images displayed using the URL are slow to display on screen.

It seems like the issue is with uploading an SVG file, which isn't supported by the web server. To fix this, you can use a plugin called 'SVG support' that allows you to upload and use SVG files without any problems.

there are no clues here to indicate it's an SVG, it could be a .bmp or an excel spreadsheet

i am trying to upload image as .webp

It looks like you're not using the latest version of WordPress. This might be causing the problem with uploading WebP images.
